# I want to restore the default java CLASSPATH of my MAc os 10.7.4

Tags: java, macos, classpath

I've asked www.google.com many times but I can't seem to figure out how to restore it to default..

I am not able to simply compile and run java file now..

```
romel$ java test.java 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: test/java
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.java
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What package is your test class in?

Assuming you haven't specified a package the command to run would be `java test`.  By running "test.java" it is looking for a class named "java" in a package (directory) named "test".

For example:

**test.java**

```
class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

---

```
$ javac test.java
$ java test
Hello World
```

---

The system classpath is in `/System/Library/Java/JavaConfig.plist`.  The default value is:

```
<key>DefaultClasspath</key>
    <string>$HOME/Library/Java:$NEXT_ROOT/Library/Java:$NEXT_ROOT/System/Library/Java:$NEXT_ROOT/Network/Library/Java:$NEXT_ROOT/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Classes/classes.jar:$NEXT_ROOT/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Classes/ui.jar</string>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this,

```
java test
```

and your class name must to be capitalized first word something like this `Test`